# Error while doing facebook integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sharekit

I am using open source code sharekit for facebook integration in iOS but i am getting error as "FT_Load_Glyph failed: glyph 65535: error 6". I tried same code on another mac machine its working fine.I tried it for all 4.0 versions but not getting any success.

Please let me know if anyone know regarding this :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this error exists with iOs 4.2

[Errors on creating a multipage PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743812/creating-a-multi-page-pdf-doc/5724421#5724421)

I was getting the same errors when showing text in languages other than English.(Your Facebook news feed may contains many languages.)