# Create pdf file from UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, pdf, pdf-generation

I was reading over [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743812/creating-a-multi-page-pdf-doc/3490719#3490719) and [this article](http://www.friendlydeveloper.com/2010/08/creating-a-multi-page-pdf-document-on-iphoneipod-touchipad-with-encryption/)

My question is how to get the content from my view into the CreateMethod.  In the article it has a call like this:

```
NSString *content = textView.text; //this is the UITextView, containing our text.
```

How do I get the content since I'm using a UITable View. . .   Actually I'd like to get the entire view with all the information before the table as well.

Any ideas or at least a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw the UITableView as an *image* - it's probably not great (you may wanna text), but this would be relatively cheap. This is just a skeleton, to get the idea:

```
if (!UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(newFilePath, page, metaData )) {
    NSLog(@"error creating PDF context");
    return;
}

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
[tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Comment: Will that grab all of the table view or only what's on the screen tho?

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate it, but I need to grab then entire table (it's an invoice and invoice details.)

Answer (score 0):

[tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

it render the table view & grab all table view & make pdf of the table view.