# PDF paging from UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, uiwebview, paging

I'm using this class to generate PDF file from a UIWebView

```
-(void)createPDFfromUI:(UIView *)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
}
```

The only problem That I have is it just generate the PDF file in one single page and I just wonder if it is possible to separate it in multi pages.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can have multipages in your PDF but for that you will have to mark the start of page each time manually using

```
 UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage
```

The idea is to do this part in for LOOP depending on the number of pages you want to generate.

Please [Go Through this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743812/errors-on-creating-a-multipage-pdf)